# How to send and receive friend request using asmack library in android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop simple chat application, I'm not that much familiar with XMPP. I have configure opnfire server, and established connection with same using asamck lib. Now I'm able  to register user with openfire, but I have some basic question about same.

1. How to start chat?
2. Is it necessary to sending, receiving, and accepting friend request before starting chat?
3. If it is, how to do it.
4. Is it required any Service, or Broadcast Receiver to receive the request or chat messages?

I have done lots of research on same, but I don't get any proper solution, please try to help me If you have solution for my all queries.

Is any reference book on XMPP fro android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

> Is it necessary to sending, receiving, and accepting friend request
>   before starting chat?

No, in openfire you can configure this.

> Is it required any Service, or Broadcast Receiver to receive the
>   request or chat messages?

No, you only need a listener in your connection. Here you can see an example:

http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Building-a-Chat-Application

Comment: Sir, have refereed and implemented same, but I'm getting presence unavailable always.

Comment: Here you see if you have friends: `Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
//Get all rosters
Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();` How many friends do you have?

Comment: that result displays one friend which I have, but when I displays all details of that friend then i get result like

Comment: Your friend is connected?

Comment: that result displays one friend which I have, but when I displays all details of that friend then i get the result like: User=XXXXXXXX, Name= xxx, Status=subscribe, Type=both, Presence Status= null, Presence Type=unavailable.

Comment: Too, I set this flag: `Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);`

Comment: Still getting presence type unavailable.

Comment: Are you subscribed to his presence? `Presence subscribed = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribed);
subscribed.setTo(jidFriend);
connection.sendPacket(subscribed);`

Comment: Sir, have written same code before displaying roster entries, but I'm still getting entry status subscribe. means the code I have written is not effecting. Please help me.

Comment: How are you doing your test? I used emulator and smack deskopt application. Add/remove friends to see the app behavior

Comment: I'm running code on two different emulator.. like user A is login on emulator5554 and user B login on emulator5556. Both are seen as available on openfire server. But when I run the code it shows presence type is unavailable, and presence status is null. I didn't discover yet why this would happenig?

Comment: Is there any issue of running both emulator on same machine? but I think this is not the issue, because both are seen as online on openfire server available on same machine.

Comment: At first line you told me, we can configure sending, receiving, and accepting setting manually on openfire, means what type of setting we have to do?

Comment: Thank You very very much for valuable guidance... but still getting presence status=null, and presence type=unavilable.

Comment: I recommend you to use a smack deskopt client to see whats happening. 1  user with emulator, 1 user with smack client deskopt

Comment: how to run 1 user with smack client deskopt?

Comment: for example, with spark you can talk to your client android and your deskopt client http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp (sorry for my english)

Comment: I don't understand what you are taking about, I have run my code for talk.google.com server, it works very finely, then what the hell with openfire. I very nervous write now, from last two days I'm facing same problem

Comment: Thank you very much.. Your suggestion is really helpful for.. i.e use a smack deskopt client. Once again Thank you very..

Comment: Hi, I know the chat is old but still have one issue I hope u can answer. I am trying to add friend using openfire and asmack in android. I am able to send request to add I can see it in my spark but unable to see it on android phone. Please help me with which packet listener to use, I am really not getting the notification for new buddy request.

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure both receiver and sender user's subscription type in the open fire at Users summary, Roster, -username- , subscription, set them to "both".