# How to get pending friend request using asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am building a chat application on Android using `asmack-android-8-4.0.6.jar` and for some reason I can't get the list of friend requests that are pending and sent while I was offline.

If the request is sent when I am online I can handle it, but if it's a request that the server resend me when connecting, I don't see it on my app, but i can see it with another client.

Is this feature not included in the jar I'm using ?

Answer (score 0):

check [This OpenFire Thread](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/50619) out, it relates also to [this SO question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739370/how-to-send-and-receive-friend-request-using-asmack-library-in-android) plus you should read through the comments and API, aSamck and Smack very well documented.